# Finding all places where a paragraph style is used?

Tags: keynote, formatting

When attempting to delete a paragraph style in Keynote, one can get the dialog that reads:

> The style you want to delete is used in the document. Choose a style to replace it:

How can one go about finding *where* in the document the style is used?

Comment: Replace it with red & italic - soon see where then... or green, bold cursive if you use red italic normally...

Comment: @SolarMike Well, sure, but that's not very satisfying. (At one time, I used a word processor that had the ability to search by _style_, but Keynote doesn't seem to have that feature.)